# How does this user earn the "Popular" and "Notable" question badges without a corresponding question?

Tags: support, badges, asking-questions

I accidentally saw [this user profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3492770/user3492770). The user has earned a silver badge named "Notable Question".

You need to have a question with 2,500 views to earn that badge. But this user has a "Popular Question" badge too, while you need 1,000 views for a question to earn that badge. This amazes me, since this user only has one question with at this moment 23 views (9:18 AM, Monday, December 22, 2014 (UTC)).

How is it possible this user has these badges?

Comment: Something similar is also present in your own meta account. You have the "Supporter" badge with "0 Votes Cast".

Comment: OT: It's easy to cheat to win that badge by yourself (but I won't publish how; you don't even need to share the link anywhere) :)

Comment: Also note, if you go to the profile page and click the badge, you get a list of the relevant posts.

Answer (score 26):

He earned that badge for a question which is [currently deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22831481/starting-mysql-database-server-mysqld-failed-debian) (only visible to 10K users). That is the reason it isn't visible to you.

Comment: Thank you. I can't see any any deleted questions. Can you?

Comment: @KushanRandima: Yes. It is a [privilege](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) of 10K users.

Comment: @KushanRandima you can see what Patrick says by clicking on [the user's badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/27/notable-question?userid=3492770).  It shows what post led to earning the badge, in this case it says "deleted".

Comment: So, the bug is that those badges haven't been deleted, right?

Comment: @alan: no. That is by design.

Comment: Just kidding; I understand that "by design" in this case means *programmatically un-awarding badges is a lot harder than awarding them, and just not worth the effort*.  But think about it: the user earned those badges because a lot of people looked at the question, indicating that it's probably worth looking at, but you can't look at it any more because the community decided it was off topic and shouldn't have been asked here in the first place.  And those make up two of the *three* badges the user has earned so far. :D

Comment: @AlanMoore: I don't care that much. He can have that silver badge...

Comment: @AlanMoore *By design* refers to political decision here, not a technical one. [Once a regular badge (not so a tag badge) is awarded, it is taken away only if it was obtained by heinous cheating.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/17854/238706)

Comment: @Palec: ...which is convenient, since it means the situation has to be detected—and the badge removed, if necessary—by a person, not a program. ;-)  But again, I was just trying to point out a bit of unintentional comedy.  Does anyone else get that those badges are **not** a reward?  They were meant to be, but now they're a (apparently) permanent reminder of that user's shame in having his question judged unworthy and yanked from the site after all these months.

Comment: @AlanMoore I think Peer Pressure is the very definition of a shame badge (though it's supposed to reward a user for admitting their post was bad).

Comment: @Palec: I went through your link. It is really useful. Now I have a clear idea about this topic. Thanks