# Is it ethical to link to a user in your own question?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, ethics

I have asked [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280940/how-does-this-user-earn-the-popular-and-notable-question-badges-without-a-corres) on Meta.

In that question I included a link to a Stack Overflow user (not me) to give a better sense of the situation.

Is that ethical, or should I avoid such actions? In such a situation, do I have to ask permission from the profile's owner beforehand?

Comment: 1. Yes, 2. if possible but don't worry too much, 3. no.

Comment: Unless it's for "name and shame" (which is very discouraged on here, and everywhere ideally), I think it's okay, and also useful to make the context clear.

Comment: @AndrewT. Thank you. But I didn't understand the phrase of "name and shame". Can you please explain?

Comment: From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_and_shame), "*To name and shame is to "publicly say that a person, group or business has done something wrong"*". In this case, try to avoid naming the person and instead focus on the real problem (e.g. the content, not the user)

Answer (score 10):

It is alright to include links to other users if this helps you giving context to your question. You do not have to ask permission to post a link to another user, however you should always avoid including user profiles if the question is about something the user would be ashamed of ("name and shame").

In general it is advised to ask yourself if you really need to include someone, or if the question is clear enough without adding links to user profiles.

Comment: Thanks. It helps. Do you have any idea about why someone has down-voted this question?? Do U see anything wrong here or any areas to be improved? Please let me know if there any. It will help to improve my self

Comment: Downvoting here often means the voter disagrees with you on the question lacks research in which case the asker could have easily searched for the solution. I think someone just disagrees with you posting the link in the question @KushanRandima.